# Using Pandas to export multiple rows of data to a csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a matching algorithm which links students to projects. It's working, and I have trouble exporting the data to a csv file. It only takes the last value and exports that only, when there are 200 values to be exported.

The data that's exported uses each number as a value when I would like to get the whole 's' rather than the three 3 numbers which make up 's', which are split into three columns. I've attached the images below. Any help would be appreciated.

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIhpH.png)

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoX8i.png)

```
#Imports for Pandas

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame 

SPA()
for m in M:
   s = m['student']
   l = m['lecturer']
   Lecturer[l]['limit'] = Lecturer[l]['limit'] - 1
   id = m['projectid']
   p = Project[id]['title']
   c = Project[id]['sourceid']
   r = str(getRank("Single_Projects1copy.csv",s,c))


   print(s+","+l+","+p+","+c+","+r)

   dataPack = (s+","+l+","+p+","+c+","+r)

   df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dataPack])
   df.to_csv('try.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting in the loop so you only end up with the last bit of data, you need to append to the csv  with `df.to_csv('try.csv',mode="a",header=False)` or create one df and append to that and write outside the loop, something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for m in M:
   s = m['student']
   l = m['lecturer']
   Lecturer[l]['limit'] = Lecturer[l]['limit'] - 1
   id = m['projectid']
   p = Project[id]['title']
   c = Project[id]['sourceid']
   r = str(getRank("Single_Projects1copy.csv",s,c))


   print(s+","+l+","+p+","+c+","+r)

   dataPack = (s+","+l+","+p+","+c+","+r)

   df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_records([dataPack]))
df.to_csv('try.csv') # write all data once outside the loop
```

A better option would be to open a file and pass that file object to `to_csv`:

```
with open('try.csv', 'w') as f:
    for m in M:
       s = m['student']
       l = m['lecturer']
       Lecturer[l]['limit'] = Lecturer[l]['limit'] - 1
       id = m['projectid']
       p = Project[id]['title']
       c = Project[id]['sourceid']
       r = str(getRank("Single_Projects1copy.csv",s,c))
       print(s+","+l+","+p+","+c+","+r)

       dataPack = (s+","+l+","+p+","+c+","+r)
       pd.DataFrame.from_records([dataPack]).to_csv(f, header=False)
```

You get individual chars because you are using from_records passing a single string `dataPack` as the value so it iterates over the chars:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(["foobar,"+"bar"])

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  f  o  o  b  a  r  ,  b  a  r

In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame(["foobar,"+"bar"])

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
            0
0  foobar,bar
```

I think you basically want to leave as a tuple  `dataPack = (s, l, p,c, r)` and use `pd.DataFrame(dataPack)`. You don't really need pandas at all, the csv lib would do all this for you without needing to create Dataframes.

Comment: The open a file worked, it displays the data of all the students in the csv. Thanks for your input, appreciate it. In the csv it skips the header, but the first columns consists of a 0. I will have to make changes to make the column structure right.

Comment: I've been instructed to use Pandas, so if in the future the data needs to be exported to MySQL it would be easier.

Comment: Do you want to use the csv header from the file or create your own

Comment: Cheers! I got it in the same way as I wanted it to be! Would you recommend sticking with Pandas if the data in the future needs to be exported to MySQL.

Comment: It depends really on what you were doing but it is pretty easy dump a csv into a new table/db  or add to an existing without needing pandas.